# Why is a declared javascript class I'm extending return console error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: [superclass] is not defined'?

Tags: javascript, class, shopify, custom-element, referenceerror

I'm trying to extend a class to take advantage of its quickAddItem methods.  However, when I go to extend it into a new class, the console error `Uncaught ReferenceError: QuickaddDrawer is not defined`. Here is the code, and below I'll outline what I've already tried.

```
if(!customElements.get("quickadd-drawer")) {
  customElements.define("quickadd-drawer", class QuickaddDrawer extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.sidecart = document.querySelector("side-cart");
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this.atcBtn = this.querySelector(".atc-btn");
      this.atcBtn.addEventListener("click", this.toggleDrawer.bind(this));

      this.quickaddBtns = this.querySelectorAll(".quickadd-btn:not([disabled])");
      this.quickaddBtns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", this.quickAddItem.bind(this)));
    }

    toggleDrawer() {
      this.atcBtn.classList.toggle("drawer--open");
    }

    quickAddItem(event) {
      const btn = event.target;
      const variantId = btn.dataset.quickAdd;
      console.log("button", btn, variantId);
      this.sidecart.addToCart(variantId);
    }
  });
}

class CardBubbles extends QuickaddDrawer {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.productCard = this.closest('product-card');
    this.bubbles = this.querySelectorAll('li>a');
    this.quickaddListings = this.productCard.querySelector('.quickadd-btn__listing');
    this.slideAnchors = this.productCard.querySelectorAll('.product-card__wrapper .swiper-slide a');
    this.initBubbles();
  }

  initBubbles() {
    this.bubbles.forEach(item=> item.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this)));
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.updateImageLink(event);
    // update available size buttons
    this.checkForData(event);
    // update add to cart button
    // update featured images
    // update circled swatch
  }

  updateImageLink(event) {
    const variantLink = new URL(event.target.href);
    this.slideAnchors.forEach(el=>{
      el.href = el.href.replace(/\/products\/(.*)/, variantLink.pathname);
    });
  }

  checkForData(event) {
    // update with available sizes
    let targetVariantJSON = document.querySelector(`product-card script[data-product-id="${event.target.dataset.productId}"]`);
    if (targetVariantJSON) {
      const data = JSON.parse(targetVariantJSON.textContent);
      this.updateQuickaddBtns(data);
      this.updateImages(data);
    } else {
      console.log('fetching JSON');
      fetch(`${event.target.href}.js`)
      .then( res => res.json())
      .then( data => this.updateQuickaddBtns(data));
    }
    // bind to quickadd functions
  }

  updateQuickaddBtns(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.available);
    let availableSizes=[];
    this.quickaddListings.innerHTML = '';
    data.variants.forEach(item=>{
      console.log(`Variant: ${item.id}, size ${item.option1} is available: ${item.available}`);
      const newButton = document.createElement('a');
      newButton.classList.add('quickadd-btn');
      newButton.dataset.quickAdd = item.id;
      newButton.innerText = item.option1;
      if (item.available == false) {
        console.log('is false, will attempt to add disabled attribute now');
        newButton.setAttribute("disabled", "");
      }
      this.quickaddListings.append(newButton);
    });
    console.log(availableSizes);
  }
  updateImages(data) {
    //update images with data
  }
}

customElements.define('card-bubbles', CardBubbles);
```

The new class and its element `CardBubbles` work fine when I extend an `HTMLElement`, though I'm at the point where I need to invoke the `QuickaddDrawer` methods, so I'd like to get this working instead of duplicating the code if possible.

I've tried different syntaxes for declaring the `QuickaddButton` class.  I've tried removing the conditional statement in case the class definition was scoped within it, as I'd seen that as how extensions were working elsewhere in the code.  I've also tried declaring the `CardBubbles` class and its element *within* the `if(!customElements.get("quickadd-drawer")) {` statement to further test if it was a scoping issue, but I get the same `ReferenceError` each time.

Big Question: Why is this class still not defined?  How can I fix it?

Bonus questions:
The `QuickaddDrawer` code was written like this when I found it.  Is there a reason for it to be wrapped in its conditional statement?  I've seen other class definitions in this code declared without the conditional.

Comment: `class QuickaddDrawer extends HTMLElement`  is an expression and thus not available outside. Just define it outside if you want to re-use it.

Comment: To put it a different way, when you create the parent class that way, as a parameter in a function call, it only exists in that context. No global class symbol will be created for `QuickAddDrawer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!customElements.get("quickadd-drawer")) {
  customElements.define("quickadd-drawer", class QuickaddDrawer extends HTMLElement {
  ...
  });
}

class CardBubbles extends QuickaddDrawer {
....
}

customElements.define('card-bubbles', CardBubbles);
```

As explained in the comments `QuickaddDrawer` is only available **within** the IF branch scope.

You could move `QuickaddDrawer` to a higher scope:

```
class QuickaddDrawer extends HTMLElement {
  ...
});
if(!customElements.get("quickadd-drawer")) {
  customElements.define("quickadd-drawer", QuickaddDrawer );
}

class CardBubbles extends QuickaddDrawer {
....
}

customElements.define('card-bubbles', CardBubbles);
```

Or, because Custom Elements ARE Classes, you might as well write:

```
if(!customElements.get("quickadd-drawer")) {
  customElements.define("quickadd-drawer", class extends HTMLElement {
  ...
  });
}

customElements.define('card-bubbles', class extends customElements.get("quickadd-drawer") {
....
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion of removing the class definition from the `if` statement worked for me.  But your last window of `customElements.define('card-bubbles', class extends customElements.get("quickadd-drawer") {` is illuminating.  I did not know you could refernce that way.  Thank you!

Comment: For extending existing components see my Dev.To blogposts: [How to cheat with Web Components](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/how-to-cheat-with-web-components-295o) and [More + Wordle  Mordle](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/more-wordle-mordle-extending-josh-his-web-components-4li)